# Why local constant variables doesnt go to .rodata section?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, constants, elf

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inc(int* p) {
        *p = *p + 1;
}

int main() {
        const int a = 10;
        inc(&a);
        printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Above program compiles without any error and the output is 11 since local variable 'a' goes into stack.

So my question is:

1. Why 'a' goes into stack. I was expecting it to go into .rodata section. But why it didn't?
2. While if I declare 'a' as a global constant variable it goes into .rodata section.

This amuses me!!

Comment: It is the C standard which allows a const variable to be mutated. With C++ compiler you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the name indicates `const` doesn't declare constants in C but variables that are not modifiable. It *must* realize it on the "stack" since recursive calls of functions must lead to different instantiations of that variable. (These would be distinguishable by their address.) That here in your case your function doesn't recurse leads to a possible optimization, but this optimization path mustn't necesserarily be taken.

As for violating the `const` property, every compiler must give you a "diagnostic" that this is to your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler's allowed to do whatever it wants.  If you declare it `static` you may get the behaviour you're looking for.

In this specific case, you're causing undefined behaviour by trying to modify a `const` value, so *really* all bets are off.

For example, I just built your exact program here with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org), and I get output of `10`.  It did give a warning about discarding the `const` qualifier:

```
example.c:9:13: warning: passing 'const int *' to parameter of type 'int *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        inc(&a);
            ^~
example.c:3:15: note: passing argument to parameter 'p' here
void inc(int* p) {
              ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Yup I see that its an undefined behavior and static would solve the issue. But I was just curious to know why gcc does this way and if there is any reason behind it?!?

Comment: When it comes to undefined behaviour, about the only reason you can count on is what was easiest for the compiler engineer to implement.  Even that's hardly a guarantee.

Comment: Okay I see compiler writer's job becomes difficult because of crappy programmers. Im unable to vote up but neways thanks for your answers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In C, "constant variables" are really variables that *you* promise not to change, nothing more. If it is local to a function, it is created, initialized, and later destroyed like any other variable. Only difference is that you'll get screamed at if you (overtly) try to change it. I.e.:

```
const int a = 15;
...
a = 17;  /* error: assignment of read-only variable ‘a’ */
...
int *p = (int *) &a;
...
*p = 117; /* Just fine, will even work making a == 117 */
```